# How to use Hour, minutes & sec in delay kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, datetime, kotlin-coroutines

I want to use `delay` in my launch function. I always use `xxxL` value for `delay`. Is there any function to convert **seconds**, **minutes** & **hours** . For example

**For 30 second**

```
delay(30)
```

**For 1 minute**

```
delay(1)
```

**For 2 Hour**

```
delay(2)
```

It's so much confusing to multiple by value. Thanks

I tried from [Delay](https://kotlinlang.org/api/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/delay.html) with [Duration](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.time/-duration/), but I am getting error in here

```
delay(Duration(1.minutes))
```

**imports**

```
import kotlinx.coroutines.delay
import kotlinx.coroutines.launch
import kotlin.time.Duration
import kotlin.time.Duration.Companion.minutes
```

**Error**

[image]

I don't know what I am doing wrong in here.

**UPDATE**

which one should I use to import?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can also use `delay(1.minutes)`.

Required import: `kotlin.time.Duration.Companion.minutes`

Comment: which import should I use for minutes?

Comment: `kotlin.time.Duration.Companion.minutes`

Comment: Why would you tack on the `.toLong(DurationUnit.MILLISECONDS)` when there's an overload of `delay` that already accepts Duration? Just use `delay(1.minutes)`

Comment: What you said should be accepted answer. @Tenfour04, you should post it as answer. I forgot about it, i was working on something else like timer with animation

Comment: I just edited yours for simplicity.

Answer (score 1):

The constructor for `Duration` is

```
Duration(long seconds, int nanos)
```

To make it work you can use following

```kotlin
Duration.ofSeconds(10).toMillis()
```

to use syntax `1.minutes` or `1.seconds` you need

```kotlin
import kotlin.time.minutes
import kotlin.time.seconds
```

Note: this libraries required API 26+

Answer (score 1):

The [delay()](https://kotlinlang.org/api/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/delay.html) function can take a `Long` value when you wants to delay by a certain amount of milliseconds or any [`Duration`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.time/-duration/).

Kotlin provides helpers to create duration given any number. You can create them with special [extension properties](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/extensions.html#extension-properties) from the Duration object.

To create duration :

```kotlin
val second: Duration = 1.seconds
val duration: Duration = 2.4.minutes
```

You can use the delay function with it

```kotlin
scope.launch {
    delay(seconds)
    delay(duration)
}
```

A duration can be converted back to milliseconds in Long with:

```kotlin
val oneSecondInMillis: Long = seconds.inWholeMilliseconds
```

Comment: why do you used `2.4.minutes` what is `2.4` mean? Is 2 minute and 4 seconds?

Comment: It's literally 2 and 4/10 minutes. That's the only way a double could be interpretted.

Comment: It's just an example to emphasize that a duration can be created with any numeral value (like a 2.4 double value). And it means 2 minutes and 40% of a minute 2m24s

Comment: @LioneLBriand, these aren't delegated properties. They're extension properties.

Comment: @LionelBriand which import should be good to use? I added in my update section.

Comment: `import kotlin.time.Duration.Companion.seconds` or change the last bit to whatever units you are using.